# Script is loaded but only executed when User is logged in

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have run into a problem where my Script is loaded but it only gets executed when I am logged in. The role of the User does not matter.

It worked perfectly last week and as far as I know, there have been no changes to the site since then.

To test this, I tried to execute following code:

```
console.log('??????????')
```

There is no other code in the file.

Here are my results:

**Not logged in:**

[I can find it in the 'Network' tab of the Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wV6m.png)

[But there are no '??????' in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOkCT.png)

**Logged in as a normal User**

[I can still find it in the 'Network' tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPJSV.png)

[There are '??????' in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IImY1.png)

**How the script is enqueued:**

```
function custom_scripts() {
    $rand = rand(1, 99999999);
   wp_enqueue_script(
     'custom', /* Name für das Script */
     get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', /* Pfad */
     array( 'jquery' ), /* jQuery ist erforderlich */
     false,
     true
   );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'js4u', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js4u/js4u.min.js', array( 'jquery'), $rand, "all");

     if( is_page(8) ) {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'create-listing', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js4u/create-listing.js',array(), $rand, "all");
     }

     if( is_page(13) ) {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'login-page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js4u/login-page.js',array(), $rand, "all");
     }

     if( is_page(14) ) {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'register-page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js4u/register-page.js',array(), $rand, "all");
     }

     wp_enqueue_script( 'primary-menu', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js4u/primary-menu.js',array(), $rand, "all");

 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts', 999 );
```

If I paste the code directly into the console, it works as intended.

I have tried it in Chrome, Firefox and Edge with the same results.

There is also no difference between Incognito and Normal mode.

This is the only file where this problem occurs, the others still work fine.

I hope you can help me :D

Update: The alert and the console.log seem to work on every page except the front page. The rest of the code still doesn't do anything.

Code that should be executed:

```
function fn() {
    let loginButton = document.querySelectorAll('#login-button-link')[1].parentNode;
    let usernameMenuItem = document.getElementById('menu-item-username');
    let firmaEintragen = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item-8199')[1];
    let favorites = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-item-my-favorites')[1];

    /**
     * Entfernt den Eintrag 'Favorites' aus dem Username Dropdown im Header
     */
    if (usernameMenuItem){
        favorites.parentNode.removeChild(favorites);
        console.log('Username Dropdown angepasst');
    }

    /**
     * Entfernt den "Firma Eintragen" Button wenn der Login-Button sichtbar ist, der User also nicht eingeloggt ist.
     */
    let loginStyle = loginButton.style.display;
    if (!(loginStyle === 'none')) {
        firmaEintragen.style.display = 'none';
        console.log('Firma Eintragen entfernt');
    }
    if (loginStyle === 'none') {
        loginStyle = 'table-cell';
        console.log('Login geändert')
    }
}
fn();
```

Comment: We need more code - is your wp_enqueue_script() directly in your functions.php?

Comment: Sorry, I just added the complete function.

Comment: Is the custom.js included in both the logged in and logged out website? What about the js4u.min.js?

Comment: btw, the last parameter cannot be a string (you are passing "all"), it must be a bool: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: have you tried alert() instead of console.log()?

Comment: js4u.min.js works correctly on both versions. 

custom.js seems to work but I can't change the script to execute an alert or a console.log, so it might be a caching problem? There are no caching plugins active. 

alert() doesnt change anything. 

Update: Both the alert and the console.log now fire on every page except the main page. What could cause this? Added this to the question.

Comment: Regarding the 'in_footer' parameter: 

custom.js and js4u.min.js are not from me, they were there before I started working here.

I don't know what the "all" does but it seems to work. It behaves the same if I enter true, false or just leave it empty so I used it for myself.

Comment: try this https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#script_debug (to activate this, you gotta start here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug)

Comment: @jasie Thank you, the SCRIPT_DEBUG constant was new to me. The code now works correctly on every page, EXCEPT the homepage, which is weird. It doesn't matter whether I load the page for the first time or if I click around a bit and then come back to the homepage, the script just doesn't execute.

Comment: Is the custom_scripts() func executed/entered at all on the homepage?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ `wp enqueue()` requires the last parameter to be a boolean, weather it is loaded in the body tag or in the head tag, standard it's `false`, meaning header.

Comment: Yes, js4u.min.js gets executed on every page, logged in or not. Do you know if there is a difference in how the page is loaded when you're logged in vs when not logged in? I also tried putting the code into a $(document).ready block which did nothing.

Comment: @Dorvalla I changed it to `false` which loaded the script earlier, then changed it to `true` which loaded it later, then changed it to `"all"` which loaded it at the exact same time as true so somehow it works even though it is a string? Thats why I used it for myself, it seems to work.

Comment: "all" is invalid as last paramter and hence "defaults" to false, as declared in the documentation. you should get warnings through WP_DEBUG (either displayed or in the log, depending on your configuration).

Comment: you have another error: the version parameter has to be string (or bool or null). in your case, it is int (return type of rand() ) - try this strval($rand). the version parameter is responsible for caching! so please read the docs carefully.

Comment: @jasie Thank you very much for your time! I changed the `$rand` variable into a string, enabled the caching plugin WP Rocket filled and cleared the cache a few times and now it works. I should've followed the docs more closely but the `$in_footer` and `$ver` parameters came from the previous dev and everything worked, so I assumed it was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct these two errors and then see, if it works:

1. The last parameter of wp_enqueue_script() needs to be a Bool. You are passing a String ("all") which problably defaults to false (it should cause a PHP warning at least).
2. The second last paramter needs to be a string, bool oder null. You are passing an Integer because that is what rand() return (it should also cause a PHP warning). Convert the int into string (e.g. through strval()).

The $ver parameter is very caching relevant! Make sure you read the documentation properly: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Also, I suggest you activate `WP_DEBUG` along with `SCRIPT_DEBUG`: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug

Last advice: delete the browser cache properly (this can be done in the browser settings).

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as intended now.

Big thanks to @jasie

Turned `$rand` into a string with `$rand = strval(rand(1, 99999999));`.

Changed `$in_footer` into `true`.

Enabled caching plugin WP Rocket and cleared the cache a few times.

Code in functions.php:

```
function custom_scripts() {
    $rand = strval(rand(1, 99999999));

   wp_enqueue_script(
     'custom', /* Name für das Script */
     get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', /* Pfad */
     array( 'jquery' ), /* jQuery ist erforderlich */
     false,
     true
   );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'js4u', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js4u/js4u.min.js', array( 'jquery'), $rand, true);

     if( is_page(8) ) {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'create-listing', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js4u/create-listing.js',array(), $rand, true);
     }

     if( is_page(13) ) {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'login-page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js4u/login-page.js',array(), $rand, true);
     }

     if( is_page(14) ) {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'register-page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js4u/register-page.js',array(), $rand, true);
     }

     wp_enqueue_script( 'primary-menu', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js4u/primary-menu.js', array('jquery'), $rand, true);

 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts', 999 );
```